# Why is VSCode not indenting .js file properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am doing tutorial about full stack web development with javascript and react on the front. I have very very litle knowledge of html and no knowledge on javascript and react beforehand.

I have recurring problem where I write code to .js file, but indentation seems to be messed up and causes things to not work properly. Otherwise code is perfect.

Here is example of what I wrote (that didin't work).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class RoomJoinPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return <p>This is the Join Room page</p>
    }
}
```

Here is example of working code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class RoomJoinPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <p>This is the room join page</p>;
  }
}
```

I get that indentation has to be done properly, but why vscode does not indent these correct automatically? Am I to learn writing code in .js files so that I first backspace improper indent and then double tap space to make it right? What am I missing here?

EDIT:
It was wrong for me to asume that indentation was problem. I did not notice that  return statement should have `;` at the end.

Comment: You have to enable autoformat (on save, on write,...) or trigger it manually. You need to configure a formatter if you have multiple formatters installed. You have to install the configured formatter if missing or configure a different formatter. The code snippets aren't valid JavaScript. It's JSX. `*.js` is the wrong extension for these files. The correct extension is `*.jsx`.

Comment: JavaScript itself does not care at all about indentation, so there has to be something else wrong. When you say that your first example doesn't work, what error do you get?

Comment: the difference (other than 4 v 2 spaces per indent level) is a `;` - not sure how you think "indentation is messed up" - it's exactly the same, just not the same amount

Comment: @Bravo you are correct. It seems that didn't notice that semicolon when comparing working and not working code. All I could see changin was the indentation, but in truth Indentation truly had nothing to do with it. Thank you.

Comment: @MosheKatz I did not particulary have any error, but the program did not render text on screen (screen was blank in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, JavaScript does not care about indentation, so your code will still work. However, it will become less readable.

There are a few fixes, though.

---

One of them is to use *Prettier*. To install it, go to the *Extensions* tab, and search for *"Prettier"*. Install the first result.

It will ask you what your default code formatter should be. Select *Prettier*. Your code should be formatted every time you save the file!

---

If you are using `.jsx`, you may have to follow the steps below.

The file extension *`.jsx`* is different from *`.js`*. This may make Prettier confused of whether it should format JSX or not.

To change it, go to *Settings*, then search for *Prettier*. Add the `.jsx` file extension, and you're done!

---

If you, however, want to use the built-in formatter, you can check it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_formatting)!

---

These solutions should help get your JavaScript and JSX get formatted!

Comment: Your answer is difficult to read because _you keep shouting_. Please limit bold and headings.

Comment: I've edited the answer to remove all boldness.

Comment: VS Code contains a JavaScript formatter. It's not necessary to install Prettier. This answer doesn't answer the question. It's a useful recommendation and a good comment, but it's not an answer. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_formatting) is the section about the built-in formatter. In the very next section, you can read that it also works with JSX.

Comment: Thanks; I've added that in the answer.

Comment: "This may make Prettier confused of whether it should format JSX or not.

To change it, go to Settings, then search for Prettier. Add the .jsx file extension, and you're done!"

Interesting, but I could not find teh spesific setting where I can add file extension. What is it called excatcly?

Comment: I had Prettier, but it seems that even though it was installed it was not in use for whatever reason.